# Highcharts line style change

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am working on [highcharts polar-spider](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-spider) . I have spent around 5 hours to find the solution to color the lines and make it think but i can't able to find the solution. So finally here so please help.

Please check below image so you can get idea about which lines i am talking about.

[image: Chart line Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding these properties to **xAxis** and **yAxis** worked for me

- `gridLineWidth` - To control the width of the line and
- `gridLineColor` - To change the color of the line
  [image]

Demo & Code:
https://jsfiddle.net/ajLyxc8r/

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [gridLineColor](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.gridLineColor), which can be set for each axis of the line chart:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'line'
    },

    accessibility: {
        description: 'A spiderweb chart compares the allocated budget against actual spending within an organization. The spider chart has six spokes. Each spoke represents one of the 6 departments within the organization: sales, marketing, development, customer support, information technology and administration. The chart is interactive, and each data point is displayed upon hovering. The chart clearly shows that 4 of the 6 departments have overspent their budget with Marketing responsible for the greatest overspend of $20,000. The allocated budget and actual spending data points for each department are as follows: Sales. Budget equals $43,000; spending equals $50,000. Marketing. Budget equals $19,000; spending equals $39,000. Development. Budget equals $60,000; spending equals $42,000. Customer support. Budget equals $35,000; spending equals $31,000. Information technology. Budget equals $17,000; spending equals $26,000. Administration. Budget equals $10,000; spending equals $14,000.'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Budget vs spending',
        x: -80
    },

    pane: {
        size: '80%'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Sales', 'Marketing', 'Development', 'Customer Support',
            'Information Technology', 'Administration'],
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        gridLineColor:'#00ff00',
        lineWidth: 0
    },

    yAxis: {
        gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
        lineWidth: 0,
        gridLineColor:'#00ff00',
        min: 0
    },
    

    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>${point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
    },

    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        layout: 'vertical'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Allocated Budget',
        data: [43000, 19000, 60000, 35000, 17000, 10000],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }, {
        name: 'Actual Spending',
        data: [50000, 39000, 42000, 31000, 26000, 14000],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                    layout: 'horizontal'
                },
                pane: {
                    size: '70%'
                }
            }
        }]
    }

});
```

```css
.highcharts-figure, .highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}
.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
}
.highcharts-data-table th {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table td, .highcharts-data-table th, .highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table thead tr, .highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
    background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
        A spiderweb chart or radar chart is a variant of the polar chart.
        Spiderweb charts are commonly used to compare multivariate data sets,
        like this demo using six variables of comparison.
    </p>
</figure>
```

(example above based on the [Highcharts Spiderweb Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/polar-spider))